# Return "true" if two columns in record are equal?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I'm looking for an possibility to check in an sql statement if various columns equal each other and return true or false:

For Example: 4 Columns (a,b,c,d)  and I want to check if a LIKE b and c LIKE d and if true then return true(or 1)...

Is this possible to do this in mysql? i'm actually solving this with php in 2 steps but this sucks..

thx for your advice

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In MySQL

```
select a = b AND c = d as is_check_true
from your_table
```

will return `1` if true and `0` otherwise.

To make this work with other DB engines you can use

```
select case when a = b AND c = d 
            then 1
            else 0
       end as is_check_true
from your_table
```